# OOP modelling- chess game different classes to use, allowing game to progress

Tags: java, oop, chess

so far I'm at a loss on how to proceed. For the moment, I'm keeping it simple having only 4 rooks and 4 bishops on the board. I have a game class which starts a game and a board class which sets the initial state of the board. I'm not sure what other classes to have, players?pieces? and how to let different players take turns, i.e. black or white assigned to the player class or piece class?(I am using a terminal scanner to get a typed input from the user)

here is what I have so far

```
public class Game {

    private static String WHITEPLAYS_MSG    = "White plays. Enter move:";
    private static String BLACKPLAYS_MSG    = "Black plays. Enter move:";
    private static String ILLEGALMOVE_MSG   = "Illegal move!";
    private static String WHITEWINS_MSG     = "White wins!";
    private static String BLACKWINS_MSG     = "Black win!";

    private Board gameBoard;


    public Game() {
        gameBoard = new Board();
    }
 // Build on this method to implement game logic.
    public void play() {

        EasyIn2 reader = new EasyIn2();

        gameBoard = new Board();    
        boolean done = false;

        while(!done) {                     //keeps looping when no one has won yet
            gameBoard.printBoard();

            System.out.println(WHITEPLAYS_MSG);

            String pos1 = reader.getString();         //gets user input ... move from... to....
            String pos2 = reader.getString();

        //not sure how to let game progress here...



            System.out.println(WHITEWINS_MSG);
            done = true;
        }
    }
}




public class Board {

    private static final char FREE         = '.';
    private static final char WHITEROOK    = '♖';
    private static final char BLACKROOK    = '♜';
    private static final char WHITEBISHOP  = '♗';
    private static final char BLACKBISHOP  = '♝';


    // people might find them useful for extensions
    private static final char WHITEKING    = '♔';
    private static final char BLACKKING    = '♚';
    private static final char WHITEQUEEN   = '♕';
    private static final char BLACKQUEEN   = '♛';
    private static final char WHITEKNIGHT  = '♘';
    private static final char BLACKKNIGHT  = '♞';
    private static final char WHITEPAWN    = '♙';
    private static final char BLACKPAWN    = '♟';

    private int boardsize;
    private char[][] board;


    public Board() {
        this.boardsize = DEFAULT_SIZE;

        board = new char[boardsize][boardsize];

        // Clear all playable fields
        for(int x=0; x<boardsize; x++)
            for(int y=0; y<boardsize; y++)
                board[x][y] = FREE;


        board[0][7] = BLACKROOK;
        board[2][7] = BLACKBISHOP;
        board[5][7] = BLACKBISHOP;
        board[7][7] = BLACKROOK;
        board[0][0] = WHITEROOK;
        board[2][0] = WHITEBISHOP;
        board[5][0] = WHITEBISHOP;
        board[7][0] = WHITEROOK;


    }


    public void printBoard() {

        // Print the letters at the top
        System.out.print(" ");
        for(int x=0; x<boardsize; x++)
            System.out.print(" " + (char)(x + 'a'));
        System.out.println();

        for(int y=0; y<boardsize; y++)
        {
            // Print the numbers on the left side
            System.out.print(8-y);

            // Print the actual board fields
            for(int x=0; x<boardsize; x++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
                char value = board[x][y];
                if(value == FREE) {
                    System.out.print(".");
                } else if(value >= WHITEKING && value <= BLACKPAWN) {
                    System.out.print(value);
                } else {
                    System.out.print("X");
                }
            }
            // Print the numbers on the right side
            System.out.println(" " + (8-y));
        }
        // Print the letters at the bottom
        System.out.print(" ");
        for(int x=0; x<boardsize; x++)
            System.out.print(" " + (char)(x + 'a'));
        System.out.print("\n\n");
}

public class W09Practical {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Game game = new Game();

        game.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what other classes to have, players?pieces? ... This totally depends on what you want to do exactly. Do you want to have a graphical user interface or only a gui? Do you need to check the moves input by the user? DO you want to have an AI to play against? Every improvement may need one or multiple classes (or be mixed into the existing classes) - which may or may not be ugly code ;)

Comment: @quant I want to make sure a move is legal for a piece, I;m not sure how to convert a1 for example to the array list yet. I want the game to keep track on who's turn it is. do I need a colour in a piece class or colour in a player class? Game should end when a player has lost all pieces